# VisualStateManager ignores RepeatBehavior="Forever"

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, visualstatemanager

I have a very simple `VisualStateGroup` that should start gradually (cubic ease) spinning animation in the `Spinning` state and stop it as soon as it exits the state. However the animation stops after the first round as if `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` was completely ignored by `VisualStateManager`:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup Name="SpinningStates">
        <VisualState Name="Spinning">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerIcon"
                                 To="360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState Name="NotSpinning"/>
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition To="Spinning" GeneratedDuration="0:0:1.0">
                <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase/>
                </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Is not `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` supported by VSM transitions? Is there a way to fix the problem?

---

Infrastructure code for example above:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.Spinner"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups/> <!--from above-->
    <TextBlock x:Name="SpinnerIcon" Text="X" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="preventFreeze" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>
<UserControl/>
```

code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SpinProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Spin", typeof(bool), typeof(Spinner), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnSpinChanged));

private static void OnSpinChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is Spinner spinner && e.NewValue is bool shouldSping)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(spinner, shouldSping ? "Spinning" : "NotSpinning", true);
    }
}

punlic bool Spin
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(SpinProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SpinProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Just thinking out loud.. Maybe RepeatBehaviour expects a From value to be defined explicitly?

Comment: @Insane interesting idea and a good lead. Even though it does not expect it in normal situation (when there is no transition/easing defined), it kind-of solves the problem. If there is `From="0"`, the animation does play forver, however it no longer plays the transition/easing, the icon is still in the first second and then it starts spinning (transition is now animating from 0 to 0?).

Comment: Can it be possible for you to update the question with a MVCE? It would help me visualize the easing problem.

Comment: @Insane sure, though it is mostly auto genered by IDE - just a named element to apply rotation to and dependency property that sets the visual states above.

Comment: Now I can see the behaviour running at my machine. You wish to achieve endless running with easing right? You can achieve it without Visual State transitions as well.

Comment: @Insane more of a start/hold/stop - I intend to place it next to a the label of a button (and bind isEnabled) and give it some easing during showing/hinding of the spinner. The problem of not using transitions is that it generally works well only when you never want to stop any animations - manual control of storyboards gets exponentially harder when they should be tied to logical states of elements.

Comment: To be precise, any solution dont *need* to use StateManager, it is just experience that things tend to get really ugly really soon without one when well... managing states.

Comment: You can add the easing to the DoubleAnimation instead of the VisualTransition. Use `<DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction> <CubicEase/> </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>`. This will give you easing every time the animation is repeated

Comment: @Insane thanks, even though it is not what I was originally after, it looks great. I will go with that animation instead, seeing how complicated it can get to mess with transitions. I will keep the question open if somebody figgures the StateManager out. Thinking about your suggestion, it should also be possible to animate from negative From to 0 during transition, however I dont think it will produce smooth animation because the derivate would not be continuous.

Comment: You can always tinker with EasingMode of easing functions. You could also try AutoReverse property of animations in this case I guess. Good luck!